# Neural Network feature priority

Tags: neural-network

there is a kind of NN that can give importance for some inputs ?

I have a problem like (actualy solved by 2 different NNs):

SITUATION 1) 
inputs: 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 : target: 23

SITUATION 2) 
inputs: 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 : target: 29

can I use the same NN for the both inputs, using the SITUATION as another INPUT for a single NN ?

One problem of this approach is that I have 50 different SITUATIONS.

Anyone with a good idea ?

Andre

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be adding another 50 input neurons and lighting one of them, signalizing your situation.
To make it smaller, you could use just 6 input neurons and light them up in binary code (situation 13 = 101100 as input for input neurons)

Other solution would be training neural network for each situation and save its weights+biases. Then for solving you would first apply weights+biases corresponding to situation you want to do and then calculate outputs.

Last option i can think of would be creating 50 different neural networks and use one you need.

I think that solution of having additional 6 neurons in binary is the riht way to go.
You can have up to 64 different situations. Adding 7th neuron can extend your situation count to 124 and every next neuron will double that

Comment: Maximus-CZ, good !! I´ve tried it with a small version (not the whole 50 different types)... the problem, is that, its not a CLASSIFICATION approach, its an REGRESSION problem. So, I would take in one input 1-50 values (specifying the situation), it doesn´t work... what I´m missing ???

Comment: So its not (int) 50, but (double) 50, so number of situation is actually infinite? And for each situation, you want different output? If not, and it is (int) 50 situations, transforming it to binary and feeding 6 neurons should work. Just remember you need to train whole dataset for each input combination.